# Ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute при вызове метода виджета

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-faq

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
def start():
    button3 = tk.Button(text="Регистрация", width = 12, command = registration,   font = ("Arial" , "12")).place(x = 200, y = 130)
    button4 = tk.Button(text = "Войти" , width = 12, command = vxod,   font = ("Arial" , "12")).place(x = 200, y = 100)
def add():
    print(entry1)
def registration():  
    global entry1
    label = tk. Label(text = "Придумайте свой ник" ,   font = ("Arial" , "8")).place(x = 400 , y = 100)
    entry1= tk.Entry().place(x = 400, y = 120)
    label = tk. Label(text = "Адрес электронной почты" ,  font = ("Arial" , "8")).place(x = 400 , y = 160)
    entry2 = tk.Entry().place(x = 400, y = 180)
    label = tk. Label(text = "Придумайте пароль" ,  font = ("Arial" , "8")).place(x = 400 , y = 220)
    entry3 = tk.Entry().place(x = 400, y = 240)
    label = tk. Label(text = "Введите ваш возраст" ,  font = ("Arial" , "8")).place(x = 400 , y = 280)
    entry4 = tk.Entry().place(x = 400, y = 300)
    button = tk.Button(text = "Зрегистрироваться" , command = add).place(x = 400 , y = 340) 
def vxod():
    label = tk. Label(text = "Ник" ,  font = ("Arial" , "8")).place(x = 600 , y = 100)
    entry1 = tk.Entry().place(x = 600, y = 120)
    label = tk. Label(text = "Пароль" ,  font = ("Arial" , "8")).place(x = 600 , y = 160)
    entry2 = tk.Entry().place(x = 600, y = 180)
    label = tk. Label(text = "Возраст" ,  font = ("Arial" , "8")).place(x = 600 , y = 220)
    entry3 = tk.Entry().place(x = 600, y = 240)
    button = tk.Button(text = "Войти").place(x = 600, y = 280)

def rules():
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.title("Правила игры")
    label = tk.Label(window,text  = "Вы игрок можете выбрать количество").pack() 
    label1 = tk.Label(window, text="кирпечей от 1 до 3 ").pack()
    label3 = tk.Label(window, text="Робот выбирает любое значение неизвестное игроку").pack()
    label4 = tk.Label(window, text = "В конце игры выводиться статистика").pack()
    label5 = tk.Label(window, text = "Время не ограничено, всего 10 попыток").pack()
    window.mainloop()

def show_image(path):
    root = tk.Tk()
    img = Image.open(path)
    width = 800
    ratio = (width / float(img.size[0]))
    height = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(ratio)))
    imag = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imag)
    panel = tk.Label(root, image=image)
    panel.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="no")
    label = tk.Label(text = "Кирпичики" ,  font=("Arial", "12")).place(x = 200, y = 0)
    button = tk.Button(text = "Правила игры", width = 12, command = rules, font = ("Arial" , "12")).place(x = 200, y = 100 )
    button2 = tk.Button(text = "Начать", command = start,  font = ("Arial" , "12")).place(x = 200 , y = 130 )
    root.mainloop()
show_image("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Кирпичики2.jpg")
```

Помогите пожалуйста получить данные из виджета Entry, я использовал глобальные переменные, ввожу текст, а программа выдает пустоту(None).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в такой конструкции:

```
entry1 = tk.Entry().place(x = 600, y = 120)
```

в `entry1` записывается не созданный объект `Entry`, а результат вызова метода `place`, который всегда возвращает `None` (так же как и `grid` и `pack`). Разделите создание виджета и его размещение:

```
entry1 = tk.Entry()
entry1.place(x = 600, y = 120)
```

Comment: Cпасибо за развернутый ответ!!!